# How do i use my array within my solveMaze function (java)?

Tags: java, function, scope

here is my code:

```
public class solving {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        readMazeFile("maze0.txt");
        solveMaze(0, 0);
     }





static void readMazeFile(String mazeFile) throws FileNotFoundException {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(mazeFile));

      //Find the height and width
      int height = input.nextInt();
      int width = input.nextInt();
      int finalHeight = (2*height) + 1;
      int finalWidth = (2*width) + 1;

    //Create the array and put data from the file in it
      char maze[][] = new char[finalHeight][finalWidth];
      input.nextLine();
         for (int row = 0; row < finalHeight; row++) {
            String fileLine = input.nextLine();
            for (int col = 0; col < finalWidth; col++) {
                  char nextChar = fileLine.charAt(col);
                  maze[row][col] = nextChar;
             }
          }
       }


    static boolean solveMaze(int row, int col) {
      char right = maze[row][col + 1];
      char left = maze[row][col - 1];
      char up = maze[row - 1][col];
      char down = maze[row + 1][col];
      //Base case is at the end of the maze
      if (right == 'E' || left == 'E' || up == 'E' || down == 'E'){
         return true;
      }
      if (right == ' '){
         return solveMaze(row, col+1);
      }

      if (down == ' ') {
         return solveMaze(row+1,col);
  } 

      if (left == ' ') {
         return solveMaze(row,col-1);
  } 

       if (up == ' ') {
          return solveMaze(row-1,col);
  }

      return false;
}





  }
```

I am trying to solve a maze that is created using the text file, I am sure there are many other things wrong with my code, but i cant test it out because i don't know how to get the maze array to work inside the solveMaze function. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: ok i got the maze to work in other functions, but now i keep getting nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Make it global by defining it outside your `readMaze()` function and then use it in your `solveMaze()` function.

   ```
   public class solving {
       /* Define it here */
       private static char maze[][] = new char[finalHeight][finalWidth];

       /* Rest of the code */
   }
   ```
2. Return it from your `readMaze()` to the Main function and then pass it in your `solveMaze()` function from the Main function.

   **Main Function:**

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       char[][] maze = readMazeFile("maze0.txt");
       solveMaze(maze, 0, 0);
   }
   ```

   **ReadMaze Function:**

   ```
   static char[][] readMazeFile(String mazeFile) throws FileNotFoundException {

       /* Rest of the code */

       /* Return maze array */
       return maze;
   }
   ```

   **SolveMaze Function:**

   ```
   static boolean solveMaze(char[][] maze, int row, int col) {
       /* Code Here */
   }
   ```